# Jquery post, with progress updates

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to be able to send a jquery $.post to a PHP file,
The php file does validation and then DB injection, which depending on
the size of the data can take a while.

It would be nice to update the user using echo's in the php file when it gets
to certain stages in the progress.

What would be the best way to do this.

Please dont ask for example code, its a simple jquery post, with multiple echo's
in the php file when it completes certain tasks and I would like to receive the updates and dynamically update the status on the html page which did the jquery post.

Comment: Well, i won't ask for a sample code then.. but what did you try/searched for solving your problem, and why didn't it work/didn't behave as you expected?

Comment: The first thing that came up was xhr, but I dont fully understand the concept and all the examples are used for uploading & downloading files.

The other option I found was this, https://hmp.is.it/update-browser-status-ajax-process/ but I was hoping for a more elegant solution if possible.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have also tried using
`ob_end_flush();
    echo json_encode($response_array);
    flush();
    ob_start();`
but doesn't seem to be getting the desired result

Comment: If your script is structured in such a way that you can echo different progress stages, you should be able to split these stages in different PHP files and call consecutive Ajax requests so that your Javascript knows at which stage it is and can display it. For a solution in a single Ajax call, i don't have an example right here, maybe i can update tomorrow

Comment: I would prefer it to all be in one php file since each stage is a separate function, maybe multiple ajax queries might be the way to go?